# How to get the next near future value to the current time in a list in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a store schedule that comes from the server. And I get the current time. I need to find the **near future** `start_time` to my current time in the list I am getting. For example, if the current time is 3:00 pm, I need to get the closest `start_time`, which is 5:00 pm. Tell me how to do it?

**here I am accessing the key 'mon'**

```
String dateFormat = DateFormat('EEE').format(timeNow).toLowerCase();
shopSchedule.templateFull![dateFormat]
```

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: I need to find the nearest next time. The main thing is that it should be the future and not the past.

Comment: As for the `mon` data, are you converting on TimeOfDay or date. Also you can compare `start_time` i think,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to get closest time after now from your `mon` list:

```
String? selectedTime;
for (var element in mon) {
  if (selectedTime == null) {
    var now = DateTime.now();
    DateTime tempDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").parse(
        "${now.year}-${now.month}-${now.day} ${element["start_time"] as String}");

    if (tempDate.isAfter(now)) {
      selectedTime = element["start_time"];
    }
  } else {
    var now = DateTime.now();
    DateTime selectedDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")
        .parse("${now.year}-${now.month}-${now.day} $selectedTime");
    DateTime tempDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").parse(
        "${now.year}-${now.month}-${now.day} ${element["start_time"] as String}");

    if (tempDate.isBefore(selectedDate) && tempDate.isAfter(now)) {
      selectedTime = element["start_time"];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly so I can find the near future tense?

Comment: yes you find near future tense @Max

Comment: @Max was it what you want?

Comment: Yes, I need to find the near future tense. I will try your code and give you an answer

Comment: I get the value (1970-01-01 08:00:00.000) into the tempDate variable. How to make the current date?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pLaO.png

Comment: The time I get is recording it in 1970 year

Comment: Everything is working now, thank you very much!

Comment: Another such question, but if the nearest time it will be the next day, can it be tracked somehow?

Comment: you want if the nearest time is next day not consider it?